# Does Windows Phone support EAP TLS?

Tags: 8.0, wifi

Is it true that Windows Phone currently doesn't have support for EAP-TLS when connecting to wifi networks? If so, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined by this active [uservoice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2281269-add-eap-tls-authentication-support-for-wifi) request, it does not support EAP-TLS and there is no workaround.

Now that [Windows 8.1](http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-phone-8-1-now-finally-supports-wpa2-eap-tls/) is out. EAP-TLS is now built in and available.

Comment: According to [this](http://wmpoweruser.com/windows-phone-8-1-now-finally-supports-wpa2-eap-tls/) site is now possible to  connect using EAP TLS  in Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 3):

The [enterprise feature pack](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2013/07/10/making-windows-phone-an-even-better-choice-for-business.aspx) for Windows Phone 8 will bring support for EAP-TLS in the first half of 2014.

Update: Apparently Microsoft has moved some features planned for the Enterprise Feature Pack into WP 8.1 ([source1](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn643706.aspx), [source2](http://www.petri.co.il/top-windows-phone-8-1-features-for-businesses.htm#), [source3](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/windows-phone-8.1-mdm-client,1-1840.html)). EAP-(T)TLS is one of those features which should be available with WP8.1.